# Is it possible to use Google Adsense on a Flex3 website?

Tags: apache-flex, adsense

Is it possible to use Google Adsense on a Flex website? I've read that while Flex can interpret PHP and Javascript, it can't directly load PHP or Javascript. Therefore, it can't handle the ad invocation codes.

All the "pages" of my flex site run straight down the middle with no variation. And I've got a logo at the top of the page. So, I was thinking that it might be possible to add the Google Adsense code in Flex's HTML template. As all of my "pages" have the same lay-out, content won't overlap any ads.

I also read that there are some cross-platform/cross-browser problems using DIV layers with Flex-- that in some browsers the Flash content will render on top of all other content, regardless of depth. Is this correct?

I thought that I'd run it by you guys before trying. Has anyone tried this idea? Any reasons that it won't work? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise that you validate that using adsense on a flash application is something approved by google as you could get a surprise later on.

Comment: Agreed. I'm concerned about the TOS. It's strange that Google doesn't come out and say, "yes, you can" or "no, you can't". I've seen lots of people posting about this question on Google's AdSense help forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call into the AdSense API directly from Flex.  It looks like there is a full set of functionality via web service that you can hook up.

Take a look: http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/